# Share variables between c files

Tags: c

I know that there are a lot of question already asked about this specific thing but none have helped me.

So I have a kernel.h file and a kernel.c file. In kernel.c I create 3 double linked list that i want to use in my main that is located in a different c file. What I want to do is that I want to use my Insert function from another dlist.c file with a dlist.h.

Right now I declare the 3 lists as extern in my kernel.h file and includes them both in kernel.c and the main.c. In main.c I include the dlist.h with all my functions for the lists and in my main I can't use the insert function with one of my lists it just said there are no definition for it.

Comment: There is no standard way to do this in C.   Some options, such as setting up and using shared memory, are system dependent.   Depending on requirements, you may wish to use an object request broker, but that typically relies on third-party libraries.

Comment: You may use a function in kernel.c and pass pointers to your variables. In this function assign pointer values and theoretically you can use these variables everywhere. But it is not bad idea to use extern command in header if you have your variables structure and named properly.

Comment: The lists are declared as struct list* Readylist so I must create a pointer for the Readylist then I guess?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/k8J9Bhww

Answer (score 1):

A good practice is to use a function which you call when you need some variable from another module (in your case another file):

kernel.c

```
//Since you have pointers, you have to use double pointers to change pointer where it points to (maybe sounds confusing)
void getLists(struct list** l1, struct list** l2) {
    *l1 = Readylist1;
    *l2 = Readylist2;
}
```

Usage in main.c

```
//Declare pointers
struct list* l1, *l2;
//Get pointer values from kernel.c
getLists(&l1, &l2);

//Use your list here..
```